# Razor Page, How to routing with tag helper asp.net core

Tags: c#, routes, razor-pages

I don't know how to get this string ?CurrentPage=2
this is my code

```
@page   "/Category/{IdCategory}"
@using RN.Sieuthibamien.com.Data.Models
@model RN.Sieuthibamien.com.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Category";
    var id = Model.IdCategory;
}
```

```
                    <div>
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item @(!Model.ShowFirst ? "disabled" : "")">
                                <a asp-page="./Category/@Model.IdCategory" asp-route-CurrentPage="1" class="page-link"><i class="fa fa-fast-backward"></i></a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="page-item @(!Model.ShowPrevious ? "disabled":"")">
                                <a asp-page="./Category/@Model.IdCategory" asp-route-CurrentPage="@(Model.CurrentPage -1)" class="page-link"><i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item  @(!Model.ShowNext ? "disabled":"")">
                                <a asp-page="./Category/@Model.IdCategory" asp-route-CurrentPage="@(Model.CurrentPage + 1)" class="page-link"><i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i></a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="page-item  @(!Model.ShowLast ? "disabled":"")">
                                <a asp-page="./Category/@Model.IdCategory"  asp-route-CurrentPage="@Model.TotalPages" class="page-link"><i class="fa fa-fast-forward"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

when I click on next link then route that I want is ./Category/{IdCategory}?CurrentPage=2, but not and result is ./Category/{IdCategory}, Sorry with my English, Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Change your tag helper to this:

```
<a asp-page="./Category" asp-route-IdCategory="@Model.IdCategory" asp-route-CurrentPage="1" class="page-link"><i class="fa fa-fast-backward"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the same page you should change this from `a asp- 
 page="./Category/@Model.IdCategory"` to
   `<a asp-page="./Category"`

and in order to navigate to your data based on what you click, just passed the currentpage to your OnGetAsync

```
OnGetAsync(int Currentpage){
   CurrentPage = Currentpage == 0 ? 1 : Currentpage;
    /// rest of the code here
 }
```